# No output log from kibana via docker - .net core

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, kibana

I'm not getting any logging output from the RestApi which is suppose to output in Kibana. All I get is this from Kibana: `No results found :(`

Containers are running fine in docker with RestApi, Elasticsearch and Kibana. So I do suspect there is something in `docker-compose.yml` that is missing and I can't seem to figure that out. Been looking for a long time with no luck. Hopefully you can see where I have gone wrong.

Still new to programming and eager to learn. Appreciate your help.

This is how the yml file looks like in .net core:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
   container_name: elasticsearch
   ports:
    - "9200:9200"
   volumes:
    - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  kibana:
   image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
   container_name: kibana
   ports:
    - "5601:5601"
   environment:
    - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200

  RestApi:
   build:
    context: C:\foo\RestApi
    dockerfile: Dockerfile 
   image: docker.restapi
   container_name: RestApi
   ports:
    - "9000:80"
   environment:
    - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add the `links` tag.

Here a snippet of my configuration

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:5.6.8         
  expose:
    - 9200
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"

kibana:
  image: kibana:6.2.3         
  links:
    - "elasticsearch"
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I'm sorry =/ The weird thing is, without dockerizing the RestApi I can see all log in Kibana but when I dockerize the RestApi no output is showing.